# net core: ManagementObjectSearcher throws exception on initializing

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to run an query with `ManagementObjectSearcher` here's my code: (net core 2.1)

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * from Win32_Printer");
    ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get();
```

on my machine (windows 10) it works fine but on the clients machine Windows Server 2012R2 i get the following error:

```
`Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer fo
r 'System.Management.ManagementPath' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitial
izationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.WmiNetUtilsHelper'
 threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ptr
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(IntPt
r ptr, Type t)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer[TDele
gate](IntPtr ptr)
   at System.Management.WmiNetUtilsHelper.LoadDelegate[TDelegate](TDelegate& del
egate_f, IntPtr hModule, String procName)
   at System.Management.WmiNetUtilsHelper..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.MTAHelper.IsNoContextMTA()
   at System.Management.MTAHelper.CreateInMTA(Type type)
   at System.Management.ManagementPath.CreateWbemPath(String path)
   at System.Management.ManagementPath..ctor(String path)
   at System.Management.ManagementPath..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.ManagementScope._Clone(ManagementScope scope, Identifier
ChangedEventHandler handler)
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher..ctor(ManagementScope scope, Ob
jectQuery query, EnumerationOptions options)`
```

I published it as win-86 exe

Comment: How-to publish as win-86 exe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems `System.Management` requires the full .NET Framework. This specific query only seem to work with .NET Framework 4.7. I've tested it with 4.0, 4.5.2 and 4.7.2 and only the latter would not give me this exception. My `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WMINet_Utils.dll` version is `4.7.2053.0`

Side note, Microsoft discourages new code to use `System.Management`, but rather use `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure`.

Comment: What's about Nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/ ?

Comment: FYI, the [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure/) NuGet package has some dependencies to get it work as it requires Windows Management Framework 3.0 be installed on Windows 7 SP1 as well as .NET Framework 4.0. See: Issue [#43 - CimSession.Create(null) does not work on Windows 7 (x86)](https://github.com/PowerShell/MMI/issues/43)

Comment: Regarding the discouraging, where is ManagementClass to be taken from, if not from System.Management - or is this type being deprecated as well ? Do you have the link to the "discouragement" from their part ?

Comment: @Veverke You can find it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/using-wmi, under ".NET Framework applications written in C#, Visual Basic .NET, or J#".